# Table appearing before appendix

Tags: appendices, appendix

My table appears before the Appendix title, at the top of the page. I tried using various commands such as [H], [H!] , [hbt!] etc, but it does not move my table. Could there be a conflict with packages here perhaps?

The bottom of my document looks like this:

```
\printcredits
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
% Loading bibliography database
\bibliography{mybibliography}

\newpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix}



\begin{table*}[h]
\caption{Average peer effect - Pre-COVID sample.}
\begin{center}
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabular}{l D{)}{)}{10)3} D{)}{)}{10)3} D{)}{)}{11)3} D{)}{)}{11)3}}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 4} \\
\hline

\hline
\end{tabular}
 \begin{tablenotes}
      \begin{footnotesize}
       \item \textit{Notes:} The table reports results of a logistic regression, explaining the probability for a dwelling to adopt a retrofit measure. 0-50 meters is a dummy variable for location between 0 and 50 meters from the nearest block leader; other distance variables are defined correspondingly (The reference category is a distance larger than 500 meters). Standard errors (clustered at community level) are in parentheses. *,**,*** indicate statistical significance at the 10\%, 5\% and 1\% level respectively.   
      \end{footnotesize}
       
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{center}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

The packages I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

% If the frontmatter runs over more than one page
% use the longmktitle option.

%\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-sc}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[hypcap=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[final]{changes}
```

Comment: table* only supporst [t] and [p], not [h].  Also, if you add any text after the table, the table gets moved to the next page.

Comment: Where is the D column type defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cas-dc class and am too lazy to download it, so I used article instead.  Also, I gave up on the tabular itself.

This puts both `\section` and the tabular inside `\twocolumn[...]` to make both full width and in the right order.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}% random text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\appendix
\twocolumn[\section{Appendix}
  \captionof{table}{Average peer effect - Pre-COVID sample.}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    \item \textit{Notes:} The table reports results of a logistic regression, explaining the probability for a dwelling to adopt a retrofit measure. 0-50 meters is a dummy variable for location between 0 and 50 meters from the nearest block leader; other distance variables are defined correspondingly (The reference category is a distance larger than 500 meters). Standard errors (clustered at community level) are in parentheses. *,**,*** indicate statistical significance at the 10\%, 5\% and 1\% level respectively.   
  \end{tablenotes}
  \vspace{\textfloatsep}]

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```